# How to get values from child components in React

Tags: reactjs, ajax

So I am just starting to use React and am having trouble gathering the input values of inputs within a child component. Basically, I am creating different components for a large form I am making, then in the encompassing component, I want to collect all the values of inputs on the children in an object I am calling data, and then send that collected input into a POST AJAX request (you can see an example in the last component I made). I can pull the values easily enough when I am inside of the components, but pulling them from the parent component I haven't figured out.

Thanks in advance. Just going through the pains right now with React so any recommendations on how to structure this better as well, I am all ears!

Here are my components:

Component one

```
var StepOne = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {title: '', address: '', location: ''};
  },
  titleChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({title: e.target.value});
  },
  addressChange: function(e) {
   this.setState({address: e.target.value});
  },
  locationChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({location: e.target.value});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="stepOne">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.titleChange} />
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>Address</label>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.address} onChange={this.addressChange} />
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>Location</label>
            <input id="location" type="text" value={this.state.location} onChange={this.locationChange} />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }, // render
}); // end of component
```

Component two

```
var StepTwo = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {name: '', quantity: '', price: ''}
  },
  nameChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({name: e.target.value});
  },
  quantityChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({quantity: e.target.value});
  },
  priceChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({price: e.target.value});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div className="name-section">
        <div className="add">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <label>Ticket Name</label>
              <input id="name" type="text" value={this.state.ticket_name} onChange={this.nameChange} />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Quantity Available</label>
              <input id="quantity" type="number" value={this.state.quantity} onChange={this.quantityChange} />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Price</label>
              <input id="price" type="number" value={this.state.price} onChange={this.priceChange} />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Final component to collect data and submit ajax request

```
EventCreation = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function(){
  return {}
},
submit: function (e){
  var self

  e.preventDefault()
  self = this

  var data = {
    // I want to be able to collect the values into this object then send it in the ajax request. I thought this sort of thing would work below:
    title: this.state.title,
  }

  // Submit form via jQuery/AJAX
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/some/url',
    data: data
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    self.clearForm()
  })
  .fail(function(jqXhr) {
    console.log('failed to register');
  });
},
render: function() {
    return(
      <form>
        <StepOne />
        <StepTwo />
        // submit button here
      </form>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Define methods in the child components that return the data that you want and then in the parent component when you are rendering the children, define refs so later on when you want to retrieve the data that you need you can call those method on the children.

```
StepOne = React.createClass({
    getData: function() {
        return this.state;
    }
});

StepTwo = React.createClass({
    getData: function() {
        return this.state;
    }
});

EventCreation = React.createClass({
    submit: function() {
        var data = Object.assign(
            {},
            this._stepOne.getData(),
            this._stepTwo.getData()
        );

        // ... do AJAX
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <StepOne ref={(ref) => this._stepOne = ref} />
            <StepTwo ref={(ref) => this._stepTwo = ref} />
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: This has plenty of upvotes & looks simpler / like less code than the value={} & onChange={} approach.. but I don't really get what's going on, why this works, or why it's acceptable in react.

Answer (score 12):

Generally speaking, you'll want to pass a function down from the parent to the children as a prop. When the children's data changes, they'll call that function as a callback.

This has the big advantage of letting your parent component keep track of all of the state in your application and pass down slices of state as props to its children, instead of having each component keep track of its own internal state. ([That's the React approach to data flow](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#data-flow).)

Your components might look something like this:

```
var StepOne = React.createClass({
  handleOnChange: function(e){
     this.props.handleChange(e.target.name, e.target.value);
  },      
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="stepOne">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" value={this.props.title} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </li>
          ...
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }, // render
}); // end of component

EventCreation = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function(){
  return {}
},
handleChange: function(name, value){
    var tmp = {};
    tmp[name] = value;
    this.setState(tmp);
},
submit: function (e){
  var self

  e.preventDefault()
  self = this

  var data = {
    // I want to be able to collect the values into this object then send it in the ajax request. I thought this sort of thing would work below:
    title: this.state.title,
  }

  // Submit form via jQuery/AJAX
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/some/url',
    data: data
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    self.clearForm()
  })
  .fail(function(jqXhr) {
    console.log('failed to register');
  });
},
render: function() {
    return(
      <form>
        <StepOne handleChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} title={this.state.title} .../>
        <StepTwo handleChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} ... />
        // submit button here
      </form>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi ajm, thanks for the help. This is definitely the way I am going to implement it. I changed the handleOnChange function in the stepOne component, think it was a spelling mistake. In my react console, I am able to see the state being rendered as i'm typing, but there is no key associated with the value being input. Is that what `title={this.state.title}` is meant to be doing within the StepOne render in the final component?

Comment: `title={this.state.title}` will pass `title` from `EventCreation`'s state down to `StepOne` as a prop. You'd then be able to access it in `StepOne` via `this.props.title` (in your case, it looks like you're setting an input's value). If you're trying to get the key for what's being input, you'd like need to pass that via a function at the `StepOne` level that calls `EventCreation`'s `handleChange` function and passes it along as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to set some [references](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html). It will allow you to reach some DOM elements easily.
Ex:

```
<input id="name" type="text" value={this.state.ticket_name} onChange={this.nameChange} ref="stepOneName"/>
```

Then, in your `submit` method, you can get it back just like this :

```
var data = {
name: this.refs.stepOneName.value
}
```

**EDIT 1:** 
You have to add a `ref` to your components too :

render: function() {
    return(
      
        
        
        // submit button here
      
    );
  }
An then, access to your element :

```
var data = {
    name: this.refs.steOneRef.refs.stepOneName.value
    }
```

[I JSFiddled your code](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/33595/) ant it seems ok for me.

Comment: I tried using this before but when I try and console the value of data, I always get a `value is not defined` error. Any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 1):

I use this approach to gathering values of form fields from the child component :

**Parent Component:**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import DetailFields from "./DetailFields";

export default function ParentComponent(props) {
  //Set initial Values
  const [model, setModel] = useState(props.initModel);

  useEffect(() => {
    setModel(props.initModel);
  }, [props.initModel]);

  //  call API
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    //...Here you have model values and you can send it to api
    callApi(model);
  };

  // Set Values from the input to the model when the values changed
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    // get the value of the field
    const value = event?.target?.value;
    //set it in the model
    setModel({
      ...model,
      [event.target.name]: value,
    });
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <div>
        <DetailFields
          model={model}
          // pass the function to child component
          handleChange={handleChange}
        />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={handleSubmit} />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

**Child Component:**

```
import React from "react";

export default function DetailFields(props){
  return (

     <div className="stepOne">
          <ul>
               <li>
                    <label>First Field</label>
                    <input id="FirstField" type="text" value={props.model.FirstField || ""} onChange={props.handleChange} />
               </li>
               <li>
                    <label>Second Field</label>
                    <input id="SecondField" type="text" value={props.model.SecondField || ""} onChange={props.handleChange} />
               </li>
          </ul>
     </div>

  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat more loosely coupled solution. It depends on you setting an `id` for each element. Basically what you're doing is calling the parent components `onChange` function that will get and set the data.

```
var StepOne = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {title: '', address: '', location: ''};
  },
  _onChange(e) {
    // set your state if needed

    // call the parent function
    this.props.onChange(
        e.target.id,
        e.target.value
    )
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="stepOne">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input id="title" type="text" value={this.state.title} onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)} />
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>Address</label>
            <input id="address" type="text" value={this.state.address} onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)} />
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>Location</label>
            <input id="location" type="text" value={this.state.location} onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)} />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }, // render
}); // end of component

var StepTwo = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {name: '', quantity: '', price: ''}
  },
  _onChange(e) {
    // set your state if needed

    // call the parent function
    this.props.onChange(
        e.target.id,
        e.target.value
    )
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div className="name-section">
        <div className="add">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <label>Ticket Name</label>
              <input id="name" type="text" value={this.state.ticket_name} onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)} />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Quantity Available</label>
              <input id="quantity" type="number" value={this.state.quantity} onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)} />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Price</label>
              <input id="price" type="number" value={this.state.price} onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)} />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  EventCreation = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
      return {}
    },
    _onChange(id, value) {
      this.formData[id] = value;
    },
    submit: function (e){
      var self

      e.preventDefault()
      self = this

      // Submit form via jQuery/AJAX
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/some/url',
        data: this.formData
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        self.clearForm()
      })
      .fail(function(jqXhr) {
        console.log('failed to register');
      });
  },
  render: function() {
      return(
        <form>
          <StepOne onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}/>
          <StepTwo onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}/>
          // submit button here
        </form>
      );
    }
});
```