# React - Can A Child Component Send Value Back To Parent Form

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, input, components

The `InputField` & `Button` are custom components that go into a form to create a form. My issue is how do I send the data back up to form so that on button click, I can fire ajax on the form with data (username & password):

```
export default auth.authApi(
  class SignUpViaEmail extends Component{

    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        email : "",
        password : ""
      };
      this.storeEmail = this.storeEmail.bind( this );
      this.storePassword = this.storePassword.bind( this );
    }

    storeEmail(e){
      this.setState({ email : e.target.value });
    }

    storePassword(e){
      this.setState({ password : e.target.value });
    }

    handleSignUp(){
      this.props.handleSignUp(this.state);
    }

    render(){
      return(
        <div className="pageContainer">

          <form action="" method="post">
            <InputField labelClass = "label"
                        labelText = "Username"
                        inputId = "signUp_username"
                        inputType = "email"
                        inputPlaceholder = "registered email"
                        inputClass = "input" />
            <Button btnClass = "btnClass"
                    btnLabel = "Submit"
                    onClickEvent = { handleSignUp } />
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    }

  }
);
```

Or Is it not recommended & I should not create custom child components within the form?

child component => `InputField`

```
import React,
       { Component } from "react";

export class InputField extends Component{

  constructor( props ){
    super( props );
    this.state = {
      value : ""
    };
    this.onUserInput = this.onUserInput.bind( this );
  }

  onUserInput( e ){
    this.setState({ value : e.target.value });
    this.props.storeInParentState({[ this.props.inputType ] : e.target.value });
  }

  render(){
    return  <div className = "">
              <label htmlFor = {this.props.inputId}
                     className = {this.props.labelClass}>
                {this.props.labelText}
              </label>
              <input id = {this.props.inputId}
                     type = {this.props.inputType}
                     onChange = {this.onUserInput} />
              <span className = {this.props.validationClass}>
                { this.props.validationNotice }
              </span>
            </div>;
  }
}
```

*Error : I get the error `e.target is undefined` on the parent storeEmail func.*

Comment: You could pass a `keyup` event handler to the inputs so the parent component state is constantly up to date. Then whenever handleSignup is called the form component already has everything it needs.

Comment: @rufio86 is right, you to need to update your parent component state first. And you need to bind `handleSignUp` callback, then you will get your state.

Comment: apologies to both @rufio86 & hawk, please elaborate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get values from child components in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35800491/how-to-get-values-from-child-components-in-react)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

React's one-way data-binding model means that child components cannot send back values to parent components **unless explicitly allowed to do so**. The React way of doing this is to pass down a callback to the child component (see [Facebook's "Forms" guide](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html)).

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    };
  }
  
  //...
  
  handleChangeValue = event => this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  
  //...
  
  render() {
    return (
      <Child
        value={this.state.value}
        onChangeValue={this.handleChangeValue}
      />
    );
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  //...
  
  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        value={this.props.value}
        onChange={this.props.onChangeValue}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Take note that **the parent component handles the state, while the child component only handles displaying**. [Facebook's "Lifting State Up" guide](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) is a good resource for learning how to do this.

This way, **all data lives within the parent component (in state), and child components are only given a way to update that data (callbacks passed down as props)**. Now your problem is resolved: your parent component has access to all the data it needs (since the data is stored in state), but your child components are in charge of binding the data to their own individual elements, such as `<input>` tags.

---

**Addendum**

In response to this comment:

> What if we render a list of the child component? Using this single source of truth in Lifting state up technique will let the parent controls all the state of all the child inputs right? So how can we access each of the value input in the child component to (which is rendered as list) from the parent component?

For this case, you may map a child component for each element in the list. For example:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  //...
  handleChangeListValue = index => event => {
    this.setState({
      list: this.state.list
        .map((element, i) => i === index ? event.target.value : element)
    });
  }
  //...
  render() {
    return this.state.list.map((element, i) => (
      <Child
        value={element}
        onChangeValue={this.handleChangeListValue(i)}
      />
    ));
```

*P.S.* Disclaimer: above code examples are only for illustrative purposes of the concept  in question (Lifting State Up), and reflect the state of React code at the time of answering. Other questions about the code such as immutable vs mutable array updates, static vs dynamically generated functions, stateful vs pure components, and class-based vs hooks-based stateful components are better off asked as a separate question altogether.

Comment: Nice answer Ian. But I'm curious that What if we render a list of the child component? Using this single source of truth in Lifting state up technique will let the parent controls all the state of all the child inputs right? So how can we access each of the  value input in the child component to (which is rendered as list) from the parent component?

Comment: @Mark I've included an addendum to address your question.

Answer (score 14):

**React class component**

Parent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Child from './child'
class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    value: ''
  }
  onChangeValueHandler = (val) => {
    this.setState({ value: val.target.value })
  }
  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <p> the value is : {value} </p>
        <Child value={value} onChangeValue={this.onChangeValueHandler} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Parent;
```

Child.js

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  class Child extends Component {
  render() {
  const { value , onChangeValue } = this.props;
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text"  value={value} onChange={onChangeValue}/> 
    </div>
  );
}
}
  export default Child;
```

**React hooks**

Parent.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Child from "./child";    
export default function Parent() {
const [value, changeValue] = useState("");
return (
  <div>
    <h1>{value}</h1>
    <Child inputValue={value} onInputValueChange={changeValue} />
  </div>
 );
}
```

Child.js

```
export default function Child(props) {
return (
   <div>
       <input
        type="text"
        value={props.inputValue}
        onChange={(e) => props.onInputValueChange(e.target.value)}/>
   </div>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Parent.js**

```
   import SearchBar from "./components/SearchBar";
    
    function App() {
      const handleSubmit = (term) => {
         //Log user input
        console.log(term);
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <SearchBar onPressingEnter={handleSubmit} />
        </div>
      );
    }

export default App;
```

**Child.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";

function SearchBar({ onPressingEnter }) {
  const [UserSearch, setname] = useState("[]");

  /* The handleChange() function to set a new state for input */
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setname(e.target.value);
  };
  const onHandleSubmit = (event) => {
    //prevent form from making a http request
    event.preventDefault();
    onPressingEnter(UserSearch);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={onHandleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="search"
          id="mySearch"
          value={UserSearch}
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="q"
          placeholder="Search the site…"
          required
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.

Answer (score -13):

You can add a "ref name" in your InputField so you can call some function from it, like:

```
<InputField 
   ref="userInput"
   labelClass = "label"
   labelText = "Username"
   inputId = "signUp_username"
   inputType = "email"
   inputPlaceholder = "registered email"
   inputClass = "input" />
```

So you can access it using refs:

```
this.refs.userInput.getUsernamePassword();
```

Where getUsernamePassword function would be inside the InputField component, and with the return you can set the state and call your props.handleSignUp

Comment: While this *would* work, it's not generally recommended to attach refs to components, much less do it to get values from child components. This problem is more immediately solved by passing down callbacks, which is the canon way to do it. (See [Facebook's React guide](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html))

Comment: Indeed, the ref approach is the easiest way in his case, but yes, callbacks would be a good choice too.

Comment: refs as string are considered a legacy code and are likely to be removed: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html