# How to get multiple values from child component in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get two values in single method of Parent Component. Pass the props value from Child to Parent Component. What is the appropriate solution?

1. Form.js (Child Component)

```
 // First method -> Here I get the value in suggestion which is then
 // passed to Parent Component via props
  onSuggestionSelected = (event, {suggestion}) => {
    this.props.getWeather(suggestion)
  }

 // Second method -> Here is the value which I want to pass via 
 // props
  onClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const value = e.target.value
    this.props.getWeather(value)
  }

 // Autosuggest Input Component
 // Here I get suggestion value
 <Autosuggest
        onSuggestionSelected={this.onSuggestionSelected}
 /> 

 // Button Component
 // Here I pass the input value to onClick method
 <MDBBtn
        type="submit"
        value={inputProps.value} 
        onClick={e => this.onClick(e)}
  >
    Search Weather
  </MDBBtn>
```

2. App.js (Parent Component)

```
getWeather = async (suggestion, value) => {
    // Here I get suggestion values
    const city = suggestion.name;
    const country = suggestion.country;

    // Here I get undefined
    console.log('VALUE', value)
}
```

So, as per code above, How to get both values from Child Component? Is it possible? Any suggestions or changes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - Can A Child Component Send Value Back To Parent Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41619166/react-can-a-child-component-send-value-back-to-parent-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle it but you cannot add two arguments and invoke the function with one argument.

one way can be adding a flag if suggestion and value are meant to behave differently,

```
   onSuggestionSelected = (event, {suggestion}) => {
    const isSuggestion = true
    this.props.getWeather(suggestion, isSuggestion)
  }

  onClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const value = e.target.value
    const isSuggestion = false
    this.props.getWeather(value, isSuggestion)
  }
```

and finally little refactor on App.js (Parent Component)

```
getWeather = (suggestionOrValue, isSuggestion) => {
    if(isSuggestion){
    //use suggestionOrValue as suggestion
}
else {
    //use suggestionOrValue as value
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With my opinion, you can merge two value into a state, then send state to Parent like this:

```
this.state = {
   suggestion: "",
   value: ""
}
```

setState when you execute two functions:

```
onSuggestionSelected = (event, {suggestion}) => {
    this.setState({...this.state, suggestion }, () => this.props.getWeather(this.state))
}

onClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const value = e.target.value
    this.setState({...this.state, value }, () => this.props.getWeather(this.state))
}
```

at Parent, you can get an object that you sent from Child:

```
getWeather = async (value) => {
    console.log(value)
    // Value here will be an object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a context provider with React v.16? 
This way you can store the handlers and values inside your Context Provider and access them globally in different components.

App.js:

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';

export const Context = createContext({
  suggestion: '',
  onSuggestionSelected: () => {},
  valueSelected: '',
  onClickHandler: () => {},
});

export class Provider extends React.Component {
  onSuggestionSelected = (suggestion) => {
    this.setState({ suggestion: suggestion.value });
  };

  onClickHandler = (valueSelected) => {
    this.setState({ valueSelected });
  };

  state = {
    suggestion: '',
    onSuggestionSelected: this.onSuggestionSelected,
    valueSelected: '',
    onClickHandler: this.onClickHandler,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export const Consumer = Context.Consumer;
```

Form.js:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Context } from './App';

export default function Form() {
  const {
    suggestion,
    onSuggestionSelected,
    valueSelected,
    onClickHandler,
  } = useContext(Context);

  return (
    <>
      // Autosuggest Input Component // Here I get suggestion value
      <Autosuggest onSuggestionSelected={onSuggestionSelected} />
      // Button Component // Here I pass the input value to onClick method
      <MDBBtn
        type="submit"
        value={inputProps.value}
        onClick={(e) => onClickHandler(e)}
      >
        Search Weather
      </MDBBtn>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution... I will try even this