# Get input Data from child component React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a React form, however, I don't use the form's Input, but trying to replace it with my component called SearchInput. This component returns a select and with following props:

```
render() {
    const options = this.state.data.map(d => <Option key={d.value}>{d.text}</Option>);
    return (
      <Select
        showSearch
        value={this.state.value}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        style={this.props.style}
        defaultActiveFirstOption={false}
        showArrow={false}
        filterOption={false}
        onSearch={this.handleSearch}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        notFoundContent={null}
      >
        {options}
      </Select>
    );
  }
```

I am super new to React. So I was trying to do smth. like this

```
class CityForm extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
      <Form onFinish={this.onFinish} >
        <SearchInput value={this.state.value} style={{ width: 200 }} />
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
       </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

Basically just rendering my SearchInput into the CityForm. However I realised, that, of course, the Form doesn't really undestand my select as it's input. So I can't really get any value out of it for further search submittion. Is there a way to render my select directly into the form's input and getting it's value as data, which can be proceeded for search (on submit)?

Answer (score 0):

I could find this out by myself. Just changing following in my child-component:

```
value={this.props.value}
onChange={this.props.onChangeValue}
```

and changing the properties in my form component to

```
<SearchInput value={this.state.value} onChangeValue={this.handleChangeValue} style={{ width: 200 }} />
```

I was able to set the deafult value and follow the change of the value. This article was super helpful though. [React - Can A Child Component Send Value Back To Parent Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41619166/react-can-a-child-component-send-value-back-to-parent-form)