# React child component causing a reaction in parent component

Tags: reactjs

I'm definitely a React noob, but I have done lots of searching and keep coming up short on this basic principle. I have a React app created via create-react-app and the structure is as follows:

```
-Parent Component
    -Child Component with some statistic values
    -Child Component (Form with Submit Button)
```

When a user interacts with the Form child component they may mash the submit button and that causes code in that component to make an xhr call to interact with my db. The result of that interaction may be a change in the stats in the other child component. How can I cause that Stats child component to refetch it's data when the submit process completes?

Right now I have the fetching code in the stats component and the submit code in the form component. Is the answer to foist all of that code up to the Parent?

I'm using class components but could flip to functional if that makes it easier.

Comment: Lifting up the state to the parent component would be the easiest and most intuitive. If the same data is used by many different components then you could use the Context API or Redux

Comment: two potential issues I see with that. 1. the submit code is now in the parent but needs access to the user input in the form child and; 2. how will the form child tell the parent that it needs to go refetch the data?

Comment: Just like you will pass the state value to the stats component you could also pass a function to the form component. Here you can find the answer to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41619166/react-can-a-child-component-send-value-back-to-parent-form

Comment: You can pass a function (submit logic) as a prop to the form child component, then pass the form state from the form child into that function. React will automatically update the view when state is changed.

Comment: I'm assuming that the test for the submit button would also move up to the parent component as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would recommend is to keep always the components as "stupid as posible", for instance, a form can be only the form itself that will call a function in the parent component and will send the data on submit to be handled, the fetch function to get the data can be in the parent component also.

I will make an abstraction with functional components which I believe are faster to elaborate:

```
export default const **ParentComponent**=()=>{
const [dataFetched,setDataFetched]=useState([])//you will store your data here

const fetchData=()=>{
Apicall to get the data and store it in data
setDataFetched(response)
}

const handleSubmit=(formValues)=>{
-API call here with the post of data(formValues in the format you need)
-after api call call function fetch to refetch the data in your other child component
fetchData()
}

return(


 <ChildWithForm
    handleSubmit={handleSubmit}/>



  <Child2withdata
data={dataFetched}
>
```

Hope it can give you some hints and if I can help do not hesitate to ask

Answer (score 0):

You can move your states from child components and function for submit to parent component. And pass all as props. Then get submit function from props and run in child component.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is shared between both child components you should move it to the parent component.

This way you could easily set the new state in the parent component after your `XHR` call and pass that state to the stats component via a prop.