# How to read the dates from a detepicker from other components?

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

This is my component `datepicker`, it prints 2 inputs with the selected dates, now I need to access those values (`checkInDate`,`checkOutDate`) from other components, can you give me any idea on how to proceed?

```
function Datepick() {
  const [checkInDate, setCheckInDate] = useState(null);
  const [checkOutDate, setCheckOutDate] = useState(null);

  const handleCheckInDate = (date) => {
    setCheckInDate(date);
    setCheckOutDate(null);
  };

  const handleCheckOutDate = (date) => {
    setCheckOutDate(date);
  };

  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="flex-row">
        <div>
          <label>initial date</label>
          <DatePicker
            locale="es"
            selected={checkInDate}
            onChange={handleCheckInDate}
            dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
          />

        </div>
        <div>
          <label>final date</label>
          <DatePicker
            selected={checkOutDate}
            onChange={handleCheckOutDate}
            minDate={checkInDate}
            dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Datepick;
```

Comment: What have you tried? There are several ways to communicate between components, from passing the state down from parent to child to context.

Comment: Have a look in this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41619166/react-can-a-child-component-send-value-back-to-parent-form

Comment: There are many ways to implement this one example is using redux, add value of datepicker in a reducer and use the vakue where it is needed